# Store and call member function with unknown arguments

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to store a member function of an unknown class with unkown arguments to be called later.

I found this code snippet to get the lambda:

```
template <auto Fn, typename T, typename R = void, typename... Args>
auto get_cb_inner(T* obj, R (T::*)(Args...) const) {
    return [obj](Args... args) -> R {
        return (obj->*Fn)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    };
}
template <auto Fn, typename T>
auto get_cb(T* obj) {
    return get_cb_inner<Fn, T>(obj, Fn);
}
```

But I can't figure out how I would store it and then be able to call it during runtime with the correct parameters.

I have a struct like this:

```
struct Job {
    void execute(Data& data, const OtherData& otherData) const {
       // do job
    }
};

auto exe_fn = get_cb<&Job::execute>(new Job());
```

What I want to do is to store this "execute" function in a lambda and then store it in a vector-like container (with other functions that may have different arguments) that can be iterated and called on.

**EDIT:**

Using @KamilCuk code I created this wrapper-struct with no mem leaks/seg faults.

```
template <typename... Args>
using exec_fn = std::function<void(Args...)>;
template <typename Job>
using job_ptr = std::unique_ptr<Job>;

template <typename J, typename R = void, typename... Args>
struct JobExecuteCaller {
    exec_fn<Args...> exec_fn;
    job_ptr<J> job_ptr;
    JobExecuteCaller (J* job, R (S::*f)(Args...) const)
        : job_ptr{job_ptr<J>(job)} {
        exec_fn = [this, f](Args... args) -> R {
            (job_ptr.get()->*f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        };
    }
    void operator()(Args... args) { exec_fn(args...); }
};

auto process = JobExecuteCaller(new Job(), &Job::execute);
JobExecuteCaller(/*args ... */)
```

Now I just have to figure out a way to store different kinds of JobExecuteCallers.

Comment: What's wrong with `auto my_lambda = [&]() { my_obj.my_member(my_arg1, my_arg2); }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean you want `std::bind`?

```
#include <utility>
#include <new>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct Job {
    void execute(int a, int b) {
       std::cout << a << " " << b << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    auto exe_fn = std::bind(&Job::execute, new Job(), 
        std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);
    exe_fn(1, 2);
}
```

I have fixed your code. You need to pass not only the type of the function member pointer, but also the address of the function member pointer to the function. That way you can call it.

```
#include <utility>
#include <new>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <typename T, typename R = void, typename... Args>
auto get_cb(T* obj, R (T::*f)(Args...)) {
    return [obj, f](Args... args) -> R {
        return (obj->*f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    };
}

struct Job {
    void execute(int a, int b) {
        std::cout << a << " " << b << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    auto exe_fn = get_cb(new Job(), &Job::execute);
    exe_fn(1, 2);
}
```

Note that both examples leak memory from `new Job()`.